# Encrypted properties on Cloud foundry with Sping Boot

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, cloud-foundry, jasypt

I have a Spring Boot application which has some encrypted values in its property file
e.g. `spring.security.user.password=ENC(ZUkuSkFAiu/k7v7G1538ouQmuSWeAuOucAVuvxLCDwwJ0mgnIdfl3N/RgiZMGeBm)`
I am using jasypt to decrypt these on the fly. This works fine running locally.

However when I deploy the app on Cloud Foundry my property file now pulls the value from vcap env variables.
e.g.
`spring.security.user.password=${vcap.services.myconfig.credentials.user.password}`

in PCF the value is added as

`user.password = ENC(ZUkuSkFAiu/k7v7G1538ouQmuSWeAuOucAVuvxLCDwwJ0mgnIdfl3N/RgiZMGeBm)`

However now my app fails to start and i get an error saying

> ERROR 22 --- [ main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter : Error
> starting Tomcat context. Exception:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
> Message: Error creating bean with name
> 'securityFilterChainRegistration' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'securityFilterChainRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'spring.security-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties':
> Could not bind properties to 'SecurityProperties' :
> prefix=spring.security, ignoreInvalidFields=false,
> ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed
> to bind properties under 'spring.security.user.password' to
> java.lang.String

Is there any reason I am missing why this works locally but not on Cloud Foundry?

UPDATE

```
cf env returns ...

    
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
     "JAVA_OPTS": "-Dspring.security.user.password=ENC\\\\(ZUkuSkFAiu/k7v7G1538ouQmuSWeAuOucAVuvxLCDwwJ0mgnIdfl3N/RgiZMGeBm\\\\)",
     "user.password": "ENC(ZUkuSkFAiu/k7v7G1538ouQmuSWeAuOucAVuvxLCDwwJ0mgnIdfl3N/RgiZMGeBm)"
    },
    "instance_name": "myconfig",
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "myconfig",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

where this sows the JAVA_OPTS version that works and also the user.password property that wont resolve

Comment: How are you adding `user.password` to CF? Are you using a user provided service? If so, how are you creating that & can you include a sanitized version of `cf env` for your app?

Comment: see update above

Comment: does this not work in application-pcf.yaml spring.security.user.password=ENC(${vcap.services.myconfig.credentials.user.password})??

Comment: Tatha, no this also fails to resolve

Comment: Part of me wonders if there's an issue with the `.` you have in the key name & how that get's flattened. I would suggest you try a couple things. 1.) remove the dot, so use something like `userPassword` and see if that work, so `${vcap.services.myconfig.credentials.userPassword}` and also try just plugging `${vcap.services.myconfig.credentials.userPassword}` into something in your application that will just log the value it receives. If you can see the value, that might give some clues as why it cannot bind.

Comment: You should be able to reference them with `${vcap.services.service-name.credentials.<key>}` though, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235792/1585136. You might also look at https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv which has a more robust way of pulling out values from bound services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.security.user.password=ENC\\(ZUkuSkFAiu/k7v7G1538ouQmuSWeAuOucAVuvxLCDwwJ0mgnIdfl3N/RgiZMGeBm\\)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I’m still unclear what the issue is with cloudy foundry environment variables though. I tried escaping the brackets in a similar way to your answer. I no longer get the original error but then the credentials aren’t accepted when I get promoted in my app.